# How do I create a DataFrame with an empty pandas Series in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, initialization, series

I'm trying to append each row of a DataFrame separately. Each row has Series and Scalar values. an example of a row would be

```
row = {'col1': 1, 'col2':'blah', 'col3': pd.Series(['first', 'second'])}
```

When I create a DataFrame from this, it looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(row)
df
   col1  col2    col3
0     1  blah   first
1     1  blah  second
```

This is what I want. The scalar values are repeated which is good. Now, some of my rows have empty Series for the column, as such:

```
another_row = {'col1': 45, 'col2':'more blah', 'col3': pd.Series([], dtype='object')}
```

When I create a new DataFrame in order to concat the two, like so

```
second_df = pd.DataFrame(another_row)
```

I get back an empty DataFrame. Which is not what I'm looking for.

```
>>> second_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': 45, 'col2':'more blah', 'col3': pd.Series([], dtype='object')})
>>> second_df
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1, col2, col3]
Index: []
>>>
```

What I'm actually after is something like this

```
>>> second_df
>>> 
  col1   col2         col3
0 45    'more blah'   NaN
```

Or something like that. Basically, I don't want the entire row to be dropped on the floor, I want the empty Series to be represented by None or NaN or something.

I don't get any errors, and nothing warns me that anything is out of the ordinary, so I have no idea why the df is behaving like this.

Comment: It's because of your series that you're passing. There will be as many rows in the df as there are items in the series, so if you have 0 in the series, you'll get 0 in the dataframe.

Comment: What power do you have over your rows? Can you change them or the series in the last column? I mean, do you produce these Series, or do you get them from other process?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I do produce the series, I've got complete control and I think for the time being, I'm just going to swap the pd.Series to np.nan if the series is empty, but I think that kinda sucks. There's got to be a way to tell DataFrame to represent an empty series as None or something.

Comment: The real question is, why do you want to append rows individually (that's an anti-pattern for dataframes).

Answer (score 0):

You *could* pass an index to make it work (and get the dataframe with `NaN` in the third column):

```py
another_row = {'col1': 45, 'col2':'more blah', 'col3': pd.Series([], dtype='object')}
second_df = pd.DataFrame(another_row, index=[0])
```

When passing all scalars and a Series, the number of rows is determined by the length of the Series – if the length is zero, so is the number of rows. You could pass singleton lists instead of scalars so the number of rows is no longer zero:

```py
another_row = {'col1': [45], 'col2': ['more blah'], 'col3': [np.nan]}
second_df = pd.DataFrame(another_row)
```

Alternatively, pass all scalars and an index like above,

```py
another_row = {'col1': 45, 'col2': 'more blah', 'col3': np.nan}
second_df = pd.DataFrame(another_row, index=[0])
```

but I'd probably just do

```py
second_df = pd.DataFrame([[45, 'more blah', np.nan]], 
                         columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

Comment: Also, see the output of: `pd.DataFrame([another_row])`

Comment: @BeRT2me indeed! But what to do with a dataframe with an empty series in a cell? Representing missing data by `NaN` is the right way to work with pandas.

Comment: Oh for sure, there are assuredly far better ways to approach what OP is doing, that just gives the *literal* answer to their question :')

Comment: Ultimately, I chose to pass `np.nan` if the series was empty. I'll leave an answer with my final solution, but essentially, I chose to manually swap the series out for nan if the series was empty.

Comment: Apparently, I'm too new on this website to upvote your answer. But I appreciate your time, thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I reworked my code to avoid having this problem. My solution is as follows:

I have a function `do_data_stuff()` and it used to return a pandas series, but now I have changed it to return

- a series if there's stuff in it `Series([1, 2, 3])`
- or nan if it would be empty `np.nan`.

A side effect of going with this approach was that the DataFrame requires an index if only scalars are passed. `"ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index"`

So I can't pass `index=[0]` hard coded like that because I wanted the DF to have the series determine the number of rows in the DF automatically.

```
row = {'col1': 1, 'col2':'blah', 'col3': pd.Series(['first', 'second'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(row)
df
   col1  col2    col3
0     1  blah   first
1     1  blah  second
```

So what I ended up doing was adding a dynamic index call. I'm not sure if this is proper python, but it worked for me.

```
stuff = do_data_stuff()
data = pd.DataFrame({
         'col1': 45,
         'col2': 'very awesome stuff',
         'col3': stuff
       }, 
       index= [0] if stuff is np.nan else None
    )
```

And then I concatenated my DataFrames using the following:

```
data = pd.concat([data, some_other_df], ignore_index=True)
```

The result was a DataFrame that looks like this

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': 1, 'col2':'blah', 'col3': pd.Series(['first', 'second'])})
>>> df
   col1  col2    col3
0     1  blah   first
1     1  blah  second
>>> stuff = np.nan
>>> stuff
nan
>>> df = pd.concat([
    df, pd.DataFrame(
            {
                'col1': 45,
                'col2': 'more awesome stuff',
                'col3': stuff
            },
            index= [0] if stuff is np.nan else None
        )], ignore_index=True)
>>> df
   col1                col2    col3
0     1                blah   first
1     1                blah  second
2    45  more awesome stuff     NaN
```

You can replace `np.nan` with anything, like `""`.